# java regular expression between characters java

Tags: java

My Java code:

```
 String subjectString = "BYWW4 AterMux TP 46[_221]  \n"
                + "FHTTY TC AterMux TP 9  \n"
                + "TUI_OO AterMux TP 2[_225]  \n"
                + "F-UYRE TC AterMux TP 2  \n"
                + "RRRDSA AterMux TP 31[_256]  ";

        String textStr[] = subjectString.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < textStr.length; i++) {
            String ResultString = null;
            try {
                Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("????????");
                Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(textStr[i]);
                if (regexMatcher.find()) {
                    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
                    System.out.println(ResultString); /// 
                }
            } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
            }
        }
```

I want the program to print the value after word (TP) and before ([) on this code to get result like below:
46
9
2
2
31

Comment: What expressions have you tried? Also, if the expression is constant (which it will be in this case), there's no need to compile it each time, just do so once before the loop (or even outside the method in a static).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp `TP\s*(\d+)\[` (double backslashes in Java code) and get a value with `regexMatcher.group(1)`.
But you should not recreate it on each iteration of the loop, you should use `Pattern.compile` once per regexp.